# How to use DOMDocument to add script to HTML5

Tags: php, html, domdocument

a) Am I right in assuming the correct format for script in head in HTML5 is `<script src="script.js"></script>`?

b) How do I achieve the correct result using the DOMDocument?

```
$domImplementation = new \DOMImplementation ();     

$docType = $domImplementation->createDocumentType ( 'html', '', '' );       

$document = $domImplementation->createDocument ( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', $docType );

$head = $document->createElement ( 'head' );

$script = $document->createElement ( 'script', '' );

$script->setAttribute ('src', 'script.js');

$head->appendChild ( $script );
```

produces

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>

    <script src="script.js"/>
```

The HTML5 validator says

> Self-closing syntax (`/>`) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript tags, even if they're loading an external file via the `src=` attribute, can't be self closing. You may need to add some non-empty content to the DOM element you're creating to force it to be non-self closing. A textnode with a single space would do.

Comment: OK changing
    $script = $document->createElement ( 'script', '' );
to
    $script = $document->createElement ( 'script', ' ' );
produces
    <script src="script.js"> </script>

Thanks for that.

Now how can I get DOmDocument to produce
    <script src="script.js"></script>
i.e. without the extra space?

Comment: That I don't know. Wonder if it does that for all tags, or are JS tags buggy? Try creating a `<p>` with no content and see if that self closes.

Comment: For reference, adding a completely empty text node does the job, it doesn't even need to have a space in it.

Comment: @MarcB This also happens for HTMLTableCellElements (that's why I ended up here with searching for the same validation error).

Answer (score 0):

For empty elements, but which are non-void elements:

```
$element= $document->createElement($name);
// $element->textContent = '' is not enough
$element->appendChild($document->createTextNode(''));
$document->appendChild($element);
```